# Как написать вспомогательный инициализатор в контексте CoreData?

Tags: objective-c, coredata

Есть класс, допустим `Item`. У него много свойств, хранится ве это в CoreData. Под Swift был такой инициализатор класса:

```
convenience init(title: String, consistOf: String, price: Int, iconImage: NSData?, id: String, imageURL: String?) {
    self.init(context: CoreDataHelper.shared.container.viewContext)
    self.title = title
    self.consistOf = consistOf
    self.price = price
    self.iconImage = iconImage
    self.id = id
    self.imageURL = imageURL
}
```

В Objective-C есть родной `-(id)initWithContext:(NSManagedObjectContext *)moc`, но ведь он инициализирует без свойств,мне не подходит.

Как написать правильный инициализатор, чтобы создавал объекты `Item` в контексте и со свойствами?

Контекст у меня `[CoreDataHelper sharedInstance].context`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Маловато Вы привели информации для того, чтобы Вам дали полноценный ответ. Ведь нам известно, что у CoreData есть 3 варианта вспомогательной генерации кода для классов, отвечающих за хранение данных: либо за Вас полностью генерируют весь класс-наследник `NSManagedObject`, который будет отвечать за представление данных, хранимых в базе, либо за Вас генерируют лишь свойства в отдельной категории (расширении), либо Вы сами создаёте всё необходимое для хранения объекта в базе данных. Я рассмотрю лишь первый случай, который представлен на картинке:

[image: Codegen = Class Definition]

Рекомендую Вам написать отдельную функцию (или статический метод класса) для создания объектов `Item`. Ведь Вы программируете на Objective-C и вспомогательные инициализаторы Вам вряд ли подойдут. Проще говоря, создайте вспомогательный класс `ItemGenerator` со следующим интерфейсом:

```
#import <CoreData/CoreData.h>
#import "Item+CoreDataClass.h"

@interface ItemGenerator : NSObject

+(Item*)createItemWithTitle:(NSString*)title
                  consistOf:(NSString*)consistOf
                      price:(NSInteger)price
                  iconImage:(NSData*)iconImage
                     itemID:(NSString*)itemID
                   imageURL:(NSString*)imageURL;

@end
```

И добавьте реализацию метода для создания объектов `Item`:

```
#import "ItemGenerator.h"
#import "Item+CoreDataClass.h"

@implementation ItemGenerator

+(Item*)createItemWithTitle:(NSString*)title
                  consistOf:(NSString*)consistOf
                      price:(NSInteger)price
                  iconImage:(NSData*)iconImage
                     itemID:(NSString*)itemID
                   imageURL:(NSString*)imageURL {

    NSManagedObjectContext* objectContext = [CoreDataHelper sharedInstance].context; // Вы утверждали, что в Вашем коде так можно получить доступ к контексту
    Item* result = [[Item alloc] initWithContext:objectContext];
    result.title = title;
    result.consistOf = consistOf;
    result.price = price;
    result.iconImage = iconImage;
    result.itemID = itemID;
    result.imageURL = imageURL;
    return result;
}

@end
```

В необходимых местах вызывайте полученный метод следующим образом:

```
UIImage* img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"img"];    
Item* i = [ItemGenerator createItemWithTitle:@"title" consistOf:@"consistOf" price:100 iconImage:UIImagePNGRepresentation(img) itemID:@"itemID" imageURL:@"imageURL"];
```

Сразу после добавления объекта в контекст можете протестировать корректность работы приложения:

```
NSManagedObjectContext* objectContext = [CoreDataHelper sharedInstance].context;
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Item"
                                          inManagedObjectContext:objectContext];
[fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
NSError* error;
NSArray *fetchedObjects = [objectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
for (Item* item in fetchedObjects) {

    NSLog(@"%@", item.title);
}
```

Если Вы всё сделали верно, то в консоли Вы увидите значение поля `title` всех сохранённых объектов.

Comment: И снова помогло, спасибо!
Но да, с моим контекстом была проблема, так к нему нет доступа.
А вобще после Swift'а это выглядит странно, для того чтобы создать объект класса необходим еще один вспомогательный класс, который будет все это делать.

Comment: @StanislavK. Погодите, вспомогательный класс вовсе не обязателен, возможно я неправильно подал свою идею. Я имел в виду, что частенько программисты на Objective-C для создания объектов делают метод-обёртку, который возвращает уже готовый объект, но так как у Вас таких сущностей как Item может быть много, то для удобства проще сделать класс, который будет отвечать за создание объектов. Вы можете всё то же самое сделать с глобальными функциями, но каждый выбирает то, что ему больше нравится.

Comment: Разобрался, и понял как делать методом, спасибо. Просто не сразу обратил внимание на то, что Вы указали на варианты генерации кода CoreDat'ой, об этом не знал, делал по аналогии со Swift'ом, но тут все мудренее.